# Chrome can't save files to the mounted drive

Tags: google-chrome

Suddenly my Chrome can't save any files on my mounted drive. When going to save in Chrome it looks fine, but after clicking save then nothing happens, and the file is not saved. Currently I am using Ubuntu 22.04 LTS.
Can anyone help? Thanks before.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem. Same with Firefox and Brave. But I can save to the disk in question from gnumeric or from Libre Office Writer (these are the only things I've tried so far).